# Update a column after every insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table structure given below.

```
CREATE TABLE `sample` (
  `PK_ID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `RQ_ID` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `BID_VAL` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_bid` double NOT NULL,
  `Last_updated` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The column `max_bid` has to be auto generated which contains `max(BID_VAL) group by RQ_ID`

I need a trigger which will update `max_bid` after `insert`

Thank you.

Comment: Have you attempted to write a trigger than updates `max_bid` after insertion? If so, please share the code with us so we can help you.

Comment: this is possibly a horrible idea by the way.

Comment: imo, I would be tempted to keep `max_bid` in a separate table as it relates to items in this table but has a different lifetime. It also has different events that cause it to change. As a side-effect, the trigger issues go away.

Comment: unfortunately mysql lacks the the INSTEAD OF clause (such as in postgresql https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtrigger.html ) in create trigger which makes this task awfully complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use procedure to that like this :

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE PROCEDURE update_max ( 
 IN PK_ID_val varchar(10),
 IN RQ_ID_VAL varchar(10) ,
 IN BID_VAL_VAL double ,
 IN Last_updated_VAL datetime 
 )
BEGIN
DECLARE calcul_max_bid double;
 insert into sample 
        (PK_ID,RQ_ID,BID_VAL,MAX_BID,Last_updated)
  values (PK_ID_VAL,RQ_ID_VAL,BID_VAL_VAL,0,Last_updated_VAL);
  SELECT 
    max(BID_VAL) into calcul_max_bid 
    FROM sample 
    WHERE 
    RQ_ID = RQ_ID_VAL
  GROUP BY RQ_ID;
 update sample set max_bid = calcul_max_bid where RQ_ID=RQ_ID_val;
END ||
DELIMITER ;
```

so instead of execute insert directly call this procedure

```
call update_max('A','RQ_1',12.0,'2016-12-12');
```

Comment: did you find a solution because i don't think you can execute update or insert on the same table if you find a solution post it here i want to know it too

Comment: I honestly didn't even look at the question. Was glad you were having fun with it and didn't want to interfere

Comment: trigger  , because procedure is working fine. in trigger you cannot execute update or insert if you find a way would love to know it

Comment: believe i'm not here to build a repetation because i'm in algeria but i'm learning here !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117496/discussion-between-charif-and-drew).

Comment: i didn't understand way it's a harmful to use trigger to do this, it is bad to use trigger?!! and way may last question i swear lol

Comment: Yeah my comment was rather cryptic and meaningless. I don't want to write a solution just to support an idea (of doing his `max()`) if I think he should not be doing it in the first place.

Comment: thank you no need to store the max() in the first place but i want to know if ican execute a insert or update inside the same table that cause the trigger!! because i have a erreur says that i cannot do that just tell me if there is way don't write thank you for you answers

Answer (score 2):

you cannot do update or insert in the same table that cause the trigger but you can do this :
update the max_bid of the record befor you insert it

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE TRIGGER  `calculate_max_bid`  BEFORE insert ON `sample`  FOR EACH ROW 
begin 
DECLARE max_bid_val double;
SELECT 
    max(BID_VAL) into max_bid_val 
FROM sample 
WHERE 
RQ_ID = new.RQ_ID 
GROUP BY RQ_ID;
if max_bid_val > new.bid_val then
 SET new.max_bid = max_bid_val;
 ELSE 
  SET new.max_bid = new.BID_VAL; 
 end if;
END ||
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: i loved this question it's challenge

Comment: i tried to call a procedure to do this: same problem always      ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'sample' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. you need to do it from you programme or manualy